# Best ROS to install on ubuntu for UAV's with raspberry pi 2

Tags: ros, uav, raspberrypi, rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have to start working on UAV's designed using raspberry pi 2. I have plan's to install ROS on Ubuntu mate. So I would like to know which ROS version supports my project requirements. If you can help me with the installation link that would be great help for me.

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222589/best-ros-to-install-on-ubuntu-for-uav%27s-with-raspberry-pi-2/) by [pradeepkb](https://answers.ros.org/users/25339/pradeepkb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-12-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jfollestad](https://answers.ros.org/users/25048/jfollestad/) on 2016-02-03**:
Have you had any success with the build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Ubuntu ARM install of ROS Indigo](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/UbuntuARM) maybe the best solution for you. If you run ubuntu mate on rpi2 you have to build ROS from source.

---

Originally posted by [flluo](https://answers.ros.org/users/7891/flluo/) with karma: 16 on 2015-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0